# Link and New Account in COC

Tags: clash-of-clans

I had a COC Account on my iPad Mini. It was on level 40 with TH 7. It was connected to one Game Center email address (for iOS Device)

On my hubby's android phone he decided to create a new Account of COC attached to one Google account also. He was on level 6 I think, TH 2.

After that we decided to link the COC account to my iPad to his Android phone so he can still play it. Linked is successful, but the problem is we cannot open the latest COC account anymore (Level 6,TH2) through his Android phone, everytime we tried to open the COC the TH 7 with level 40 is being prompted, even though we signed into the Google account.

How can we retrieve that??
I believe we cannot *unlink* it anymore,but how can we retrieve the latest COC account?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you did and what you are trying to do? I'm not sure what you mean by "to link the COC account to my ipad to his android phone".

Comment: @galacticninja The answer might give a solution, but I think the questions are far apart. Both are about accessing old accounts on a device, but in this case it got 'overshadowed' by a new account, and in the other question the save game data was wiped out.

Comment: @Joachim I think it's pretty much the same thing. If your save / village was wiped for some reason, it will be replaced or 'overshadowed' by a new one. Both of these cases are of saves / villages replaced by another one. The solution is also the same: they have to contact Supercell to resolve the issue. The saves / villages and the accounts or devices they are assigned to are in Supercell's servers.

Comment: @galacticninja But as long as it is unknown whether the old files are actually gone (which is a logical assumption - don't get me wrong), isn't it better to treat both questions as different? Your solution might be the only correct one, though.

Comment: @Joachim I don't think the old saves / villages are gone in both cases. All of those are stored at Supercell's servers. The issue on both cases is on what account or device those saves are supposed to be assigned to. Supercell can reassign those saves/villages to their proper accounts/devices.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like his game save may have been overwritten by yours on his android phone. I think the best way to use a different account on a device that already has another account is to completely delete the game from your device (your game is saved in the cloud) and then re-download it and when you open it the first time it will let you sign in to an account. Then it will load the save under that email address account. There's no guarantee this will work now though since one of the two account may have been overwritten by the other but its your best bet to do it this way to know for sure.

Comment: I already deleted the entire game and created a new Google account also, but still the same .. The Account of COC which has TH 7 is the one appearing,